# How to run SequentialAnimation in the background?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm designing Qt5.7/QML application. The main idea is that pressing a button will trigger shell command which takes long time. The results of this command should be reflected in widgets.
In the meantime, I need SequentialAnimation to run, to show the user that something is happening in the background. So I start the animation and then call the process which sends the shell command.
But the animation seems to be freezed as the entire GUI until the shell command returns.
Any suggestions?
QML Code:

```
    CircularGauge {
        id: speedometer_wr
        x: 199
        y: 158
        value: valueSource.bps
        maximumValue: 400
        width: height
        height: container.height * 0.5
        stepSize: 0
        anchors {
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            verticalCenterOffset: 46
        }
        style: DashboardGaugeStyle {}

        NumberAnimation {
            id: animation_wr
            running: false
            target: speedometer_wr
            property: "value"
            easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
            from: 0
            to: 300
            duration: 15000
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: button_benchmark
        x: 168
        y: 26
        width: 114
        height: 47
        text: qsTr("Benchmark")
        tooltip: "Execute the performance test"
        checkable: true
        function handle_becnhmark() {
            speedometer_wr.value = 0;

            // Uncheck the button
            button_benchmark.checked = false;

            // Start the animation
            animation_wr.start();

            // Run the benchmark
            var res = backend.run_benchmark();

            // Stop the animation
            animation_wr.stop();

            speedometer_wr.value = parseFloat(res.split(",")[0]);
        }
        onClicked: {handle_becnhmark()}
    }
```

Cpp Code:

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QtDebug>
#include "backend.h"
#include <QRegExp>

BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

QString BackEnd::run_benchmark() {
    qDebug() << "in run_benchmark";
    QProcess proc;

    // Execute shell command
    proc.start(<LONG_SHELL_COMMAND>);
    if (!proc.waitForStarted())
        return "";
    if (!proc.waitForFinished())
        return "";

    // Get the results, parse and return values
     QString result(proc.readAll());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  It sounds as if you're simply forgetting to process events while the shell command is running.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem of singlethread applications. You need to run your execution of shell command in the another thread. Just look at [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) example of using. Main thing is that you need a signal-slot based communication between you GUI and backend (if you are calling some "hard" functions in backend).

Working with threads is make sence in many areas like working with hard drive (reading/writing to file), requests to server or database. All of this can be done synchrony or [asynchrony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)). Base meaning for you -  would it be freezes main process or not (answer - asynchronous methods wouldn't).

In your app are using QProcess to call some external command. QProcess start() method will execute this command asynchronously by itself. It means you no need to use QThreads. But it make sence if you are using `waitForFinished()`. If you will read [QProcess reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#synchronous-process-api) you will see that `waitForStarted()` and `waitForFinished()` methods is a synchronous. That means they will freeze main process and GUI indeed.

So what you need is

- declare pointer to QProcess in class header (it would be better to use `QSharedPointer<QProcess>`)

  ```
  class BackEnd : public QObject {

       ...
   private slots:    
       void handleProcFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
   signals:
       void executionEnds(const QString &res);
   private:
       QProcess* proc;
  }
  ```
- In source you need  initialize `proc` and connect QProcess [finished()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) signal to slot that will push the output of executed by `proc` command with another signal in `BackEnd`.

  ```
   BackEnd::BackEnd(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
        proc = new QProcess();
        connect(proc, &QProcess::finish, this, &BackEnd::handleProcFinished);
   }
   void handleProcFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus) {
        //check code
        ...
        QString result("");
        if (all is fine) {
            result = proc->readAll();
        } else {
            //debug or something else 
        }
        emit executionEnds(result);
   }
  ```

In QML side it will be something like this:

```
Button {
    onClicked: {
        speedometer_wr.value = 0;
        // Uncheck the button
        button_benchmark.checked = false;
        // Start the animation
        animation_wr.start();
        // Run the benchmark
        var res = backend.run_benchmark();
    }
}
Connections {
    target: backend //[name of some contextProperty which will be emiting the signals]
    onExecutionEnds: {
        animation_wr.stop();
        if (res != "") {
            speedometer_wr.value = parseFloat(res.split(",")[0]);
        }
    {
}
```

Comment: I'm a new comer to Qt/QML. Can you please also add the code for the Thread class and how to use it?